# I am concerned with mysql configuration is not optimized enough for doing a good job, how to tell?

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration

I want to know the basic parameters/configuration for mysql to work great.

What are they? How to determine?

Using phpmyadmin, the status params marked red color seems needed to alter to optimize, but what's the basic ones that I should work on first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a fairly neat perl script called mysqltuner.pl (available at the domain of the same name, or [here](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl))

you need shell access (and a mysql admin user login) - but it will look at your instance, config and some stats and make basic recommendations that could provide a base from which to work.

while it's a good starting point, it certainly isn't an absolute diagnostic tool & band-aid - I would still have a go with the numerous web resources dealing with MySQL performance tuning, and preferably start (on a development box) understanding how to measure your current performance, understand indexes and how they are applied and how different mysql datafile/db storage types work and what suits your environment.

as someone once muttered in Oracle training, there is no "faster=true" switch.

Answer (score 2):

There are entire [documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-parameters.html), [web sites](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) and [books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101716) devoted to that topic.  There's no possible way your question can be adequately answered here--especially without more information.

I suggest reading through some of the links above, and using google.  And if you get stuck somewhere, then post a new, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mysqltuner, Tuning-primer, mytop, MySQLReport,...

For more detail about those tools, check the next link....

http://www.serveradminblog.com/2011/03/tuning-mysql-performance-howto-part-1/

Of course everything depends on your situation and application which uses database...